# Adding to Columns when To Others are Equal

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I add two columns (amount, amount2) if they have the same value in multiple columns (Account,Account2) using UPDATE statement. I want to keep all rows even if Account <> Account 2. Also i want them in two columsn only Account and Amount. I am using MS Access sql view. *** I want to update the table not just use a select statement***

For example: I want to add Amount and Amount2 columns only if Account, Account 2 columns match.

I want that result end to be only two columns, the Account and the amount that was added together.

```
Account Amount Account2 Amount2
1234576  4      1234576    4
4444444  10     4564888    11
456789   2      456789      2
000000   1      1111111     6
```

Comment: Have you tried any code?  You have something written that is not working?

Comment: Yes the code below works and adds both columns when account and account2 are equal but it still leaves columns (account2, amount2) there. I cannot use a DROP on them because there is some on those columns that are <> (not equal).    UPDATE allocation SET amount = amount + amount2
WHERE account=account2;

Comment: Eh.. I've shared an answer, but now I'm unsure what you want. You can't have a column present for half your table, and removed for the other half. You can set them to `Null`, however.

Comment: You would have to do a self join (left) on the Account = Account2 and take the sum of Amount and Amount2. Take care of the NULLs.Then when you have a nice result,  you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server  to convert it to UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is non-normalized table design, and I recommend you adjust your design instead, but this can easily be achieved:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET [Amount] = [Amount] + [Amount2],
[Amount2] = Null,
[Account2] = Null
WHERE [Account] = [Account2]
```

Then if you want to move the account and amount to a single column after:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Account, Amount)
SELECT Account2, Amount2
FROM MyTable
WHERE Account2 IS NOT NULL Or Amount2 IS NOT NULL
```

Then, remove the unnecessary columns

```
ALTER MyTable DROP COLUMN Account2, Amount2
```

Comment: thank you Erik. This added both columns but left the <> ones on columns account2, and amount 2. Is there anyways to put them under column account, and amount ? I need to compare data with another table and have them the same format. Only two columns (account and amount).